# How to make Vegemite at home

Tags: yeast

Could someone make their own? Vegemite is a yeast extract made from the remains of commercial beer production. Vegemite has an extreme salt level; a home made variant would probably lower the salt level to some extent. The broad intent would be to use the home made vegemite on toasted cheese sandwiches. A colour improvement would also be desirable: a cream coloured vegemite spread would be my choice.

Comment: Are you sure it's the salt content you want reduced? Because if it is actually the sodium content, it won't help any. The main flavor in vegemite comes from monosodium glutamate, which is, per definition, high in sodium.

Comment: How about DIY Marmite? https://msmarmitelover.com/2011/04/how-to-make-your-own-marmite.html

Comment: @Tetsujin You might want to post this as an Answer; the settling process that they suggest in that blog post seems like it might remove the need for a centrifuge.

Comment: The soup of nutrients that is condensed to make vegemite is extremely nutritious. Without the added salt to preserve it it would spoil in a couple hours. You'd probably have to freeze your product to have any kind of shelf life. Or make small batches and consume them quickly. Not an obstacle, just something to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, you need industrial machinery.**

Part of the manufacturing process of producing Vegemite involves using a centrifuge to separate out the yeast cell membranes from the rest of the product. As a result, without access to such a centrifuge, it is not possible to make Vegemite.

[Here](http://www.convictcreations.com/culture/foodwine.htm) is a description of the process I found through a Google search:

> Spent brewer's yeast is sieved to get rid of hop resins, and washed to remove bitter tastes. Then it is suspended in water at a temperature greater than 37 C with no nutrients: the yeast cells die, and vitamins and minerals leach out. Then the proteolytic (protein-splitting) enzymes take over, breaking the yeast proteins down into smaller water-soluble fragments, which also leach out. The yeast cell membrane is unruptured during this time, and can be removed by centrifuging. The clear light brown liquid is then concentrated under a vacuum to a thick paste (the vacuum helps preserve flavours and vitamin B1, thiamine). It is seasoned with salt, and a small proportion of celery and onion extracts to increase the palatability.

Comment: Yeast extract can be sourced online.

Comment: And people eat it.

Comment: As "industrial" machinery goes a centrifuge and vacuum chamber are very accessible. It is easy to find plans online to make both at a level that will probably suffice for making small amounts of vegemite.

Comment: @Sobachatina I wouldn't recommend trying to DIY a centrifuge. It's the sort of thing that could potentially kill people if it fails and shards of metal or plastic go flying out.

Answer (score 3):

You could instead try making your own Marmite.

Excerpts copied from [MsMarmiteLover's Blog - HOW TO MAKE YOUR OWN MARMITE](https://msmarmitelover.com/2011/04/how-to-make-your-own-marmite.html)
Please read the whole piece for more background.

> My role as MsMarmitelover meant that I was able to go straight to the
>   top: after some negotiation with the Marmite authorities, I was given
>   a telephone date with  St.John O. Skelton, Master Blender of the
>   Marmarati Order or, more prosaically, Quality and Innovation Expert at
>   the Marmite factory in Burton On Trent. He was willing to help me but
>   darkly intimated that making Marmite was “dangerous and hard to
>   control”.
>
> RECIPE FOR HOME MADE MARMITE:
>
> A litre of Brewer’s yeast (top fermentation from a brewery)   A little
>   sea salt   1 onion, diced   2 carrots, diced   1 turnip, diced   1/2
>   celery stick, diced
>
> 1. Put a litre of brewer’s yeast with a little salt, in a bain-marie. Simmer at blood heat, 30 to 40 ºc for ten hours or overnight.
> 2. Then simmer this mixture at 50 to 60 º c for 2 to 3 hours.
> 3. Boil at low temperature 90ºc  for half an hour. (In the factory they have a special machine for this, or you could ascend a mountain
>      of 10,000ft, to achieve low altitude boiling)
> 4. Filter though coffee papers or a sieve and cheesecloth
> 5. Let it cool for a day or so. It separates further.
> 6. Filter again.
> 7. You then want to convert it to a paste. This is best achieved by putting it in a large flat pan and simmering. On an Aga, you can
>      simply leave the pan on the lid for a few hours. Keep an eye on the
>      mixture.
> 8. Meanwhile boil up all the vegetables until they are cooked. Strain off the liquid and incorporate into the Marmite paste.
> 9. Let the mixture reduce into a Marmite like texture. Do not allow it to burn: “We do not want to develop caramel notes” warned St.John.
>
> The entire process takes about ten days.   This home-made Marmite
>   admittedly tastes different, like something German and healthy in a
>   tube. Lacking the specialist equipment to ‘debitter’ the yeast, it
>   will have beerier flavours, rather like the Guinness or XO Marmite.
>   It was a comfort to know that I could, in a pinch or say, a calamitous
>   event such a terrorist attack on the Marmite factory, DIY my own
>   Marmite. But realistically, I’ll probably stick to shop-bought.
>
> *Update:* the main problem was the bitterness of the brewing yeast. The solution is to wash the yeast. You achieve this by putting the top
>   fermentation in a jar full of water. Eventually the yeast will settle
>   on the bottom of the jar. Pour off the water and fill the jar again
>   with fresh water. Do this several times to wash the yeast. Then follow
>   the recipe above.